# How to overcome an odd error when converting a BigInt to a DateTime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, casting

I have what I thought was going to be a simple cast/convert, but i am getting an odd error.

Here is my sql:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,1322510754374,104)
```

But i get this error:

```
 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

I also tried:

```
select cast(1322510754374 as datetime)
```

but i get the same error

which i am trying to figure out. Is there another way to convert a bigint to a datetime?

I am expecting something like today's date:2011-11-29 17:26:52.257, but the int i have shown is for an earlier day.

because i need to compare it to the

```
 getDate()
```

Thanks.

Comment: What date are you expecting to get from that number?

Comment: What does your big int represent?  It certainly doesn't look like days.  Is it seconds, or milliseconds?  And from what date is it based?  (Or maybe it's in ticks?)

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson: I have added an edit to the Original post

Comment: I'm still not seeing how you're getting `1322510754374` from `2011-11-29 17:26:52.257`...

Comment: Your time ends with `.257seconds` yet 257 doesn't appear in your big int anywhere.  I can't see any mechanism for how that number relates to that date, please elaborate on the relationship between the two?

Comment: Your style parameter (104) [is meant to be used when the *expression* is a DateTime type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), not when you're trying to *convert* to a DateTime type.

Comment: @Dems: I have added an update and edit

Comment: @iwant_B_smrtr - You still need to tell us what that big int represents.  Is it a number of seconds since 1AD?  Which still gives about the year 42,000.  Or is it something else?  Unless we know what the number IS or MEANS, then there is no way to help you.

Comment: @Dems: i don't know yet what it is supposed to look like because, it is coming in from a sybase server that i am not allowed to access, i only have one example. and that is what i have to figure out.  maybe that is impossible?

Comment: @iwant_B_smrtr - Is there anyone with access to that sybase server that can explain to you exactly what that number represents?  It makes no sense to me in any time unit I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Dems: That is a good idea, it's my professor's.

Comment: @Dems: He said it is a LongLong? but i have never heard of that, when i asked him what it represented, he just hung up the phone, but i can't find it anywhere in my text book or notes..

Comment: I'm hazarding a guess, but I think that number is the decimal representation of the 64-bit unsigned int that Sybase uses for storing timestamps... here's the spec that can be used to reverse that value back into something that resembles a datetime: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/CACHFDAB.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, my best guess, and it's a reasonable one, is that it is in milli seconds from 1st Jan 1970.

You can't use numbers that big in DATEADD, etc.  So here are two options...

```
DECLARE @stupid BIGINT
SELECT  @stupid = 1322510754374

SELECT CAST(@stupid / 86400000.0 + 25567 AS DATETIME)

SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @stupid % 86400000, DATEADD(DAY, @stupid / 86400000, '1970-01-01'))

-- Both Give...  2011-11-28 20:05:54.373
```

You need to double check that somehow, using a date you KNOW.  But it seems quite likely to me...

And tell your professor I'm glad not to be working with someone so bloody unhelpful.

Good luck to you :)

Comment: Thanks Dems for all of your help and guidance, i think i'll be good w/ this one now!

Answer (score 0):

You are recieving this message because the number in the statement is much to large to convert to a date... The largest number being 2958463 which equates to 9999-12-31

To add the Time to it simply add a decimal place to the number eg: 2958463.123

If you are hardcoding the bigint number try doing it in reverse first this will give you the bigint.

This is the closest statement I have to your date:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, 40874.726, 104)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the *number* appears to represent number of days since the minimum date (Jan 1, 1900). Since, as you say, the maximum possible value of this is ~3 million, this can be readily represented by an `int` (or a float, if you need time), rather than a `bigint`.

Comment: @Aaron : You are assuming the number represents days.  Even if it is actually a number of seconds it still equates to 42000 years.  I really recommend you don't make assumptions.

Comment: @Dems: I am basing my answer off the questions code examples and explaining why the error occurs.